# Cloudant search query not returning expected result

Tags: javascript, database, cloudant, node-red

I'm using Cloudant and I created a search index. However, I'd like the index to return the term I'm querying. I mean I want to get a data which has a specific date that I chose.

1.) I have created a cloudant database and loaded it with some data. 
[image]

2.) I have created a search index.

[image]

3) Node set-ups
[image]

4) And function content.

[image]

I've expected to see whole data about this exact "ts" variable. But I got this:

[image]

I have been struggling with this for a few days and can't seem to get this working. I am sure it's just a Newbie issue. 
Many thanks in advice.

Answer (score 0):

A search index uses the Apache Lucene library for text pre-processing and indexing. It's designed for chopping up sentences into words and words into stemmed tokens for "free text" search, i.e. finding the documents that best match a multi-word phrase. You can optionally choose the type of stemming which is performed by specifying the "analyzer" when creating the index, that is the text pre-processing algorithm used to break up the strings.

If you want to keep the string intact, then choose the "keyword" analyzer:

[image]

You may also want to investigate using Cloudant Query, whose type=json indexes would not pre-process your timestamp string.

Comment: Thank you for the descriptive explanation. I have tried "Keyword" option as you said but unfortunately, there is no difference in debug output.